# How to access and Read ACL information in Eucalyptus walrus (open source 2.0.3)?

Tags: object, amazon-s3, bucket, eucalyptus, walrus

i am working on Eucalyptus Walrus 2.0.3 Open Source .

all Bucket(create , list, delete) Object (upload,download,delete ) and ACL operations able to perform using Jets3t API. Except sharing resources i.e bucket , object. Please Help weather problem is with Eucalyptus or API ?

Note : for accessing i am using Head Request which always returning me false.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest upgrading to Eucalyptus 3.2.2. 2.0.3 is really old and the API support has improved significantly in newer versions.

Hope that helps.